# Display Popup Message in Same Page, for HTML Contact Form by PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a contact form on my index.html that works with a contact.php file. I need to display a popup message after submitting the form for "message sent" or "something went wrong" without leaving the index.html. Currently, it displays the message in a popup on a blank page.

I truly tried to solve it and I checked a lot of similar questions here, truth is i'm new to php and js (*I'm like Jon Snow, I know nothing*) and I just couldn't figure out a solution for my case.

I appreciate any help :)

*PHP code:

```
<?php
  
if($_POST) {
    $visitor_name = "";
    $visitor_email = "";
    $email_title = "";
    $concerned_department = "";
    $visitor_message = "";
    $email_body = "<div>";
      
    if(isset($_POST['visitor_name'])) {
        $visitor_name = filter_var($_POST['visitor_name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $email_body .= "<div>
                           <label><b>Visitor Name:</b></label>&nbsp;<span>".$visitor_name."</span>
                        </div>";
    }
 
    if(isset($_POST['visitor_email'])) {
        $visitor_email = str_replace(array("\r", "\n", "%0a", "%0d"), '', $_POST['visitor_email']);
        $visitor_email = filter_var($visitor_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
        $email_body .= "<div>
                           <label><b>Visitor Email:</b></label>&nbsp;<span>".$visitor_email."</span>
                        </div>";
    }
      
    if(isset($_POST['email_title'])) {
        $email_title = filter_var($_POST['email_title'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $email_body .= "<div>
                           <label><b>Reason For Contacting Us:</b></label>&nbsp;<span>".$email_title."</span>
                        </div>";
    }
      
    if(isset($_POST['concerned_department'])) {
        $concerned_department = filter_var($_POST['concerned_department'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $email_body .= "<div>
                           <label><b>Concerned Department:</b></label>&nbsp;<span>".$concerned_department."</span>
                        </div>";
    }
    
    
    if(isset($_POST['visitor_message'])) {
        $visitor_message = htmlspecialchars($_POST['visitor_message']);
        $email_body .= "<div>
                           <label><b>Visitor Message:</b></label>
                           <div>".$visitor_message."</div>
                       </div>";
    }
    
    
    if($concerned_department == "billing") {
        $recipient = "test@mail.com";
    }
    else if($concerned_department == "marketing") {
        $recipient = "test@mail.com";
    }
    else if($concerned_department == "technical support") {
        $recipient = "test@mail.com";
    }
    else {
        $recipient = "test@mail.com";
    }
    

    $email_body .= "</div>";
 
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n"
    .'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n"
    .'From: ' . $visitor_email . "\r\n";

    
  
    if(mail($recipient, $email_title, $email_body, $headers)) {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript"> window.onload = function(){
          alert("Thank you for contacting us. You will get a reply as soon as possible.");
        }</script>';
      

    } else {
      echo '<script type="text/javascript"> window.onload = function(){
        alert("We are sorry but the email did not go through.");
      }</script>';

    }
      
} else {
    echo '<script>alert("Something went wrong.")</script>';
}
?>
```

*HTML code:

```
<div class="form">
          <form action="/php/contact.php" method="post">
            <div class="elem-group">
              <input type="text" id="name" name="visitor_name" placeholder="Your Name" pattern=[A-Z\sa-z]{3,20} required>
            </div>
            <div class="elem-group">
              <input type="email" id="email" name="visitor_email" placeholder="Your E-mail" required>
            </div>
            <div class="elem-group">
              <input type="text" id="title" name="email_title" required placeholder="Reason For Contacting Us" pattern=[A-Za-z0-9\s]{8,60}>
            </div>
            <div class="elem-group">
              <textarea id="message" name="visitor_message" placeholder="Your Message" required></textarea>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="button white">Send Message</button>
          </form>
</div>
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the best way is to use AJAX. My proposition is to create a JS sript that is collecting data and executing php code.

Small change in html:

```
<div class="form">
    <div class="elem-group">
          <input type="text" id="name" name="visitor_name" placeholder="Your Name" pattern=[A-Z\sa-z]{3,20} required>
    </div>
    <div class="elem-group">
        <input type="email" id="email" name="visitor_email" placeholder="Your E-mail" required>
    </div>
    <div class="elem-group">
        <input type="text" id="title" name="email_title" required placeholder="Reason For Contacting Us" pattern=[A-Za-z0-9\s]{8,60}>
    </div>
    <div class="elem-group">
        <textarea id="message" name="visitor_message" placeholder="Your Message" required></textarea>
    </div>
    <button id="contact_submit" type="submit" class="button white">Send Message</button>
</div>
```

In fact you already has IDs of inputs, creating user side code should be very easy in jQuery:

```
$("#contact_submit").click(function(){
    //Collecting data
    let name = $("#name").val();
    let email = $("#email").val();
    let title = $("#title").val();
    let message = $("#message").val();
    
    //AJAX sending data to php code
    $.post("/php/contact.php",
        {
            visitor_name: name,
            visitor_email: email,
            email_title: title,
            visitor_message: message,
        },
        function(response){
            //Response from PHP in alert 
            //for example: if You use echo "Something went wrong" the message in alert will be the same.
            alert(response);
        }
    );
});
```

The only thing i would change in PHP is response:

```
<?php
  
if($_POST) {
    $visitor_name = "";
    $visitor_email = "";
    $email_title = "";
    $concerned_department = "";
    $visitor_message = "";
    $email_body = "<div>";
      
    if(isset($_POST['visitor_name'])) {
        $visitor_name = filter_var($_POST['visitor_name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $email_body .= "<div>
                           <label><b>Visitor Name:</b></label>&nbsp;<span>".$visitor_name."</span>
                        </div>";
    }
 
    if(isset($_POST['visitor_email'])) {
        $visitor_email = str_replace(array("\r", "\n", "%0a", "%0d"), '', $_POST['visitor_email']);
        $visitor_email = filter_var($visitor_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
        $email_body .= "<div>
                           <label><b>Visitor Email:</b></label>&nbsp;<span>".$visitor_email."</span>
                        </div>";
    }
      
    if(isset($_POST['email_title'])) {
        $email_title = filter_var($_POST['email_title'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $email_body .= "<div>
                           <label><b>Reason For Contacting Us:</b></label>&nbsp;<span>".$email_title."</span>
                        </div>";
    }
      
    if(isset($_POST['concerned_department'])) {
        $concerned_department = filter_var($_POST['concerned_department'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $email_body .= "<div>
                           <label><b>Concerned Department:</b></label>&nbsp;<span>".$concerned_department."</span>
                        </div>";
    }
    
    
    if(isset($_POST['visitor_message'])) {
        $visitor_message = htmlspecialchars($_POST['visitor_message']);
        $email_body .= "<div>
                           <label><b>Visitor Message:</b></label>
                           <div>".$visitor_message."</div>
                       </div>";
    }
    
    
    if($concerned_department == "billing") {
        $recipient = "test@mail.com";
    }
    else if($concerned_department == "marketing") {
        $recipient = "test@mail.com";
    }
    else if($concerned_department == "technical support") {
        $recipient = "test@mail.com";
    }
    else {
        $recipient = "test@mail.com";
    }
    

    $email_body .= "</div>";
 
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n"
    .'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n"
    .'From: ' . $visitor_email . "\r\n";

    
  
    if(mail($recipient, $email_title, $email_body, $headers)) {
        echo 'Thank you for contacting us. You will get a reply as soon as possible.';
    } else {
      echo 'We are sorry but the email did not go through.';

    }
      
} else {
    echo 'Something went wrong.';
}
?>
```

And it should work, Only thing i could not find was "concerned_department" but i hope you will be albe to add it by yourself. In case you would have problem with it, let me know.

Comment: Thank you! I tried your suggestion and indeed now it displays the popup message inside the same page. The only problem is, now it doesn't perform any kind of validation, sends to recipient whatever is filled in the inputs, even all blank

Comment: You have to do a validation in php file and send echo response if something is blank or not properly written.

Answer (score -1):

I would give an suggestion to use an alert box as an popup. The code for the same is :

Example:
Add this to your file where you are checking the logic :

```
if (move_uploaded_file($file, $destination)) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO files (pdf_file) VALUES ('$filename')";
        if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
            header("location:form5.php?upload=success");
        }
    } else {
        header("location:form5.php?upload=notsuccess");
    }
}
```

And now add this to your main file :

```
<?php 
      if (isset($_GET['upload'])) {
        if ($_GET['upload'] == 'success') {
          echo '<script>alert("Data added Successfully")</script>';
        }
        if ($_GET['upload'] == 'notsuccess') {
          echo '<script>alert("Data Not added")</script>';
        }
      }
     ?>
```

This will give you an Alert box if the event is successful or unsuccessful stating the same.